# how do i get dynamic array of objects in java

Tags: arrays, object, dynamic, runtime

I am trying to create a simple console based app where customers are involved and i am thinking of creating one object for each customer who visits .
so i thought of creating an array of objects but i have to mention the number of objects to be created in advance how can i dynamically get new objects with new name dynamically

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RentACarMain {


        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {

            int j=0,i,ch=0,inp;


            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

            CustomerDetails[] cd=new CustomerDetails[101];

            for(i=0;i<100;i++)
            {
                cd[i]=new CustomerDetails();

            }
                        do
            {


            System.out.println("Enter 1 to add new customer details");

            System.out.println("enter 2 to display details customers");
            System.out.println("press 3 exit");

            System.out.println("enter your choice");
            ch=Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            sc.nextLine();


            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:
                j=j+1;

                System.out.println("enter customer name..");    
                String cust_name_main=sc.nextLine();
                e[j].setCust_name(cust_name_main);  

                System.out.println("enter customer id");
                String c_id=sc.nextLine();
                e[j].setLicense_num(c_id); 

                break;

            case 2:

                       e[j].display();

                }

            }while(ch!=3);



            }   

}
```

now here i dont know the number of customers who are going to visit...so is there any option to dynamically get new different objects of same class

Answer (score 0):

You need a more dynamic collection, such as [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<CustomerDetails> cd = new ArrayList<CustomerDetails>();
```

Then you can add whatever number of elements you might want:

```
cd.add(new CustomerDetails());
cd.add(new CustomerDetails());
```

So as you can see, `ArrayList` differs in syntax for regular arrays. Like, to get an element at a specific position, you wouldn't do `cd[7]` for instance, but do this instead:

```
cd.get(7);
```

[Here are some more examples](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html) on how to use ArrayList, including on how to iterate over them.

Comment: actually i got the arraylist part..but cd.add(new CustomerDetails) how can i call a function which is in other class...coz i cant use that classes object directly